# div moving sideways and deminsions

Tags: html, css-position

I have a div menu that position:fixed; when setting up in my html editor it looks good, then testing locally through a browser when you maximize or minimize the browser size it stays at the position and at some points will cover up elements. I was this div to stay inside my bodyline area, never up int he header area nor in the footer area. so basically i want it to stop when scrolling down and footer appears it should stop right on top of it. Also need to know how to stop it from jumping the screen when resizing browser. Any help?

Comment: dont really need a grammer lesson thanks. My point was unquestionable and there easily. Especially from you thanks. I was typing fast while working on the coding at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Javascript if you want it to behave certain ways if the users screen is at certain scroll amounts (like stopping the position fixed when it is hitting the footer)

With jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {  // Called whenever a user scrolls on your page
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 200) { // User is close enough to header, leave element absolute (or however you want it)
        $('#fixed-element-id').css('position', 'absolute');
        // Other logic
    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() > 800) { // user is close enough to footer, leave element absolute (or however you want it)
        $('#fixed-element-id').css('position', 'absolute');
        // Other logic
    } else { // User is somewhere that the element needs to follow their scrolling
        $('#fixed-element-id').css('position', 'fixed');
        // Other logic
    }
});
```

Comment: ok thank you Mash.question is now, since I have no jQuery experience is that would I need to have a javascript for the jQuery to call? Or no? Also is that the code I would use that you posted or is it an example? Thank you for answering quickly

Comment: @nextlevelgamingCO jQuery is a javascript library that makes life a lot easier.  You can do the same thing here with default javascript, just looks messier.  Yes, this is an example, it is commented so you can understand what each section does.

Comment: so you are saying i would not need to have a javascript to call on that the jQuery is actually javascript but in a cleaner format? i see your comments, though let me ask what does the $ signs do?

Comment: $ is an alias for jQuery, which is a function that takes a selector string to a DOM element.  You might want to create a separate question or investigate further on jQuery yourself if you do not understand it.

Comment: also reading the jQuery, the element     else if scrollTop > 800    what if my footer changes height by my bodyline which has an auto height incase there is more content added

Comment: You can use $('#footer-id').offset().top instead of 800.  This will return the distance the footer is from the top of your page.

Comment: ok thank you Mash, thank you very much. For answering question as well as answering my comments. do not mean to bother you, just wanted to grasp that code a little better.

Comment: Mash how would i place this code? <script type="text/javascript"> or inside the div i am making fixed and so forth?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15494/discussion-between-mash-and-nextlevelgamingco)